# linq query must return a string

Tags: c#, linq

I use `HtmlAgilityPack` to get data from a website for a hobby project. I want to get the shoe article number from a site that sells shoes.

But my linq query doesn't return a string. Instead it returns the type:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode,string>
```

How can I get the query to simply return a string?

```
foreach (var node in query)
{
   Shoe shoe = new Shoe();

   var num = from x in node.Descendants()
             where x.Name == "img" && x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "thumb lazy"
             select x.Attributes["title"].Value.Substring(11);

   shoe.articleNumber = Convert.ToInt32(num); //error

   shoes.Add(shoe);
}
```

The error: InvalidCastException was unhandled.

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode,System.String]'
>   to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your LINQ query returns a collection. Use `First`/`FirstOrDefault`/`Single`/`SingleOrDefault` to get only one element from the collection:

```
var num = (from x in node.Descendants()
           where x.Name == "img" && x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "thumb lazy"
           select x.Attributes["title"]).First().Value.Substring(11);
```

Comment: +1 for listing all four options. To OP - note the difference between First/Single and First/SingleOrDefault: non-default throws exception if not found and with default will return the default value for returning type.

Comment: That works and very understandable. Thanks. I knew that there was something wrong, but had incorrectly tried to change the node.Descendants to node.FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only going to be one entry that matches your query, you just need to modify it to use FirstOrDefault() or First():

```
foreach (var node in query)
{
   Shoe shoe = new Shoe();

   var num = (from x in node.Descendants()
         where x.Name == "img" && x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "thumb lazy"
         select x.Attributes["title"].Value.Substring(11)).First();

   shoe.articleNumber = Convert.ToInt32(num);

   shoes.Add(shoe);
}
```

Just bear in mind that the above will fail with an exception if the item is not present.

Answer (score 0):

your query does not return a single result but a list of results. In your case this will be a list containing a single id. You should modify it to this:

```
var num = (from x in node.Descendants()
             where x.Name == "img" && x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "thumb lazy"
             select x.Attributes["title"].Value.Substring(11)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Difference between `single, singleorDefault ,first ,FirstorDefault`
[Here](http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/)